# Auto adjusting web page to screen size (HTML)

Tags: html, css

I have tried several different sources on the Internet. I am not using bootstrap; I enjoy doing my site from scratch. It helps me program.

I can't get my web page to auto adjust to the screen size. For example if you make the browser smaller the page collapse nice and neat.

I tried these codes from here: http://www.gonzoblog.nl/2013/01/16/11-useful-css-code-snippets-for-responsive-web-design/

but my web page **doesn't** collapse like the example.

```
<!--
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

   -->




<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sunpacking.css">
<title>Sun Packing WebSite</title>
<link href="../../Documents/Sun Packing/sun.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
.div1 {
    margin: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div style="width:800px; margin:0 auto;">


<div id="container">
data 
</div>



/*Sun Packing CSS */

    /*
body{

 padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;

}

*/




#container {
    float: none;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: red;
   width: 100%; /* 95px*/

    height: 100%; /*1400px*/
    color: red; 
}
```

Comment: Coding is not about copy-pasting random examples from the internet. It's about *understanding* how those examples work, and *learning* from them so you can *apply the concepts* to your own code.

Comment: I do understand that, but it is not like I couldnt figure it out in a second I have been trying for sometime now.

Comment: You really should title your question something useful, and not how desperate you are for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by closing your HTML containers, and giving a good example of what you've tried.

If you set an explicit width, `width: 800px;`,  that's the width it will be rendered at.

Try setting the container's `max-width` for that and set the width to expand to that

The way that I usually do it:

```
.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentages instead of pixels. Pixels will give you a fixed width. Percentage with keep thing proportional.

Here is a good article to help you understand what the different measurements mean.
Once you understand what they mean, you should be able to make a better selection depending on the usage you expect.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Nice try I changed to percentage element don't want to move down +/-130% doesn't affect it at all